# QT Network reply won't give me back result from PHP script

Tags: php, c++, xml, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

Hi all I have one problem.
I am connecting QT with php script..Everything works fine, but can somone help me how to receive php result from it.
here is my code :

```
void MainWindow::Dodaj_korisnika(QUrl url)
{
    //reply = qnam.get(QNetworkRequest(url));
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    QUrl params;
    params.addQueryItem("action","Dodaj_korisnika");
    params.addQueryItem("ime",ui->lineEdit);
    params.addQueryItem("prezime",ui->lineEdit_2);
    params.addQueryItem("broj",ui->lineEdit_3);
    params.addQueryItem("adresa",ui->lineEdit_4);

        QByteArray data;
        data.append(params.toString());
        data.remove(0,1);

        QNetworkRequest request;
        request.setUrl(url);
        request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,
        QVariant("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
        QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
        QNetworkReply *reply = manager->post(request, data);
        connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
}
```

And I have found on forums that I need to use this function:

```
void MainWindow::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    QString data = reply->readAll().trimmed();
    // document.setContent(reply);
}
```

But ofc I am not getting anything into this function..Is it possible to read from QT manager variable? I am receiving xml result. And I want to put it as QDomDocument is that possible?
Please give me some hint or some example if you have some time..
Thank's all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the PHP script received something?

- First you are creating a signal and slot each time you are posting
- Second you create the connection after posting
- Third verify that your query is well formed and that the php script is receiving it. If you have the script log\print incoming messages

Edit: This is How it should look like

```
// early in the code, like in the constructor 
void MainWindow::init(){
  this->manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
  connect(this->manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), 
          this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
}

void MainWindow::Dodaj_korisnika(QUrl url){

    QUrl params;
    params.addQueryItem("action","Dodaj_korisnika");
    params.addQueryItem("ime",ui->lineEdit);
    params.addQueryItem("prezime",ui->lineEdit_2);
    params.addQueryItem("broj",ui->lineEdit_3);
    params.addQueryItem("adresa",ui->lineEdit_4);

    QByteArray data;
    data.append(params.toString());
    data.remove(0,1);

    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(url);
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,
    QVariant("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

    //Here you don't need to get the reply, it will be the same given to 
    //MainWindow::replyFinished
    this->manager->post(request, data);

}

void MainWindow::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply){
    //Use the reply as you wish
}
```

Comment: Yea I am triggering script. So can you give me some example..how to change my code? So I can make one class so I can access to database? And how to check if connection is okay? And then I just call all thing's I need to trigger php script.. So can you please help me so I can communicate to my server. It is oracle databse btw which is working with php. I am getting xml as result..I mean I should get them. Thank you sir in advance.

Comment: okay thank you..but I am still not getting anything into reply variable in replyfinished function

Comment: I not getting anything into reply variable..When I print it out it says "" like empty string..I am returning XML but I should get it as string right?

Comment: Welcome back :). Can you print `reply->error()` ? It will help.

Comment: It means [QNetworkReply::ProtocolUnknownError](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworkreply.html#NetworkError-enum) : the Network Access API cannot honor the request because the protocol is not known. Your URL should contain the correct protocol, ie "qt.nokia.com" will cause this error while "http: //qt.nokia.com" will not. Look at [network manager](http://doc.trolltech.com/main-snapshot/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) too.

Comment: you were right.. thank you.. can I ask you one more thing. As I gett that string back...How can I put it in QDomDocument object I tried `document->setContent(reply);` but it seems it's not working..any idea maybe

Comment: This is another problem. Accept this answer, try a few times, and post another question if you are stuck.